# Uploading image to icloud using cloud kit throws error ios

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, icloud, cloudkit

I am facing one issue. Error is thrown when image is uploaded to `icloud` using cloud kit. It throws following error:

```
(< CKError 0x7ffad06b6780: "Internal Error" (1/5000); "Couldn't create a PCS identity">)
```

When image is not uploaded with other data, then other data is successfully uploaded.
Here I have provided code I used to set image for uploading.

```
var noteRecord: CKRecord!
if let url = imageURL {
  let imageAsset = CKAsset(fileURL: url)
  print("imageAsset \(imageAsset)")
  noteRecord.setObject(imageAsset, forKey: "noteImage")
}
```

Comment: And what do you got in that print ?
`print("imageAsset \(imageAsset)")`

Comment: What is the exact error code if you do a: let errorCode:CKErrorCode = CKErrorCode(rawValue: error!.code)!

Comment: @Ragnar When I print it shows :- <CKAsset: 0x7fe254947700; UUID=420CFFC3-54C7-430A-9A4F-2E125991DEBE, path="~/Documents/temp_image.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a user-specific issue that occurs with the iCloud Keychain and iCloud Drive folders after a user enables iCloud Drive on one of their devices.

Example log:

> ```
> Oct 17 00:38:17 hostname.local com.apple.iCloudHelper[1284] :
> PCSIdentityCollectionSetup: {type = mutable dict, count = 3, entries
> => 0 : {contents = "kPCSSetupUsername"} = {contents = "appleID"} 1 : {contents = "kPCSSetupDSID"} = {contents = "<>"} 2 : {contents =
> "kPCSSetupPassword"} = {contents = "<>"} } Oct 17 00:38:17
> hostname.local com.apple.iCloudHelper[1284] :
> __PCSAccountHasStingrayIdentities Oct 17 00:38:19 hostname.local com.apple.iCloudHelper[1284] : PCSHasStingrayIdentities: YES Oct 17
> 00:38:21 hostname.local com.apple.iCloudHelper[1284] :
> PCSCopyStingrayIdentity: {length = 1845, capacity = 1845, bytes =
> 0x628207313082072d0c0f67616d63616c ... ab42b25d58020101} (error:
> (null)) Oct 17 00:38:21 hostname.local com.apple.iCloudHelper[1284] :
> PCSIdentityCollectionSetup failed The operation couldn’t be completed.
> (OSStatus error -25244 - SecItem failed to delete on private identity)
> ```

A combination of iCloud keychain sync on the user's current device (or any other shared device they just associated with their account) or changing the permissions/deleting and rebuilding the shared iCloud folders associated with this user's keychain/account should solve this issue.

Related discussion:

[Apple Stack Exchange - Setting up iCloud results in cloudd error messages](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/210126/68852)

[Apple Support Communities - after upgrading to Yosemite iMac reboots random reboots randomly](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6657232?tstart=0)